# Disable default global using in C# 10

Tags: c#, .net, c#-10.0

How can I disable the new default global usings in C# 10?

See here: [Add default global usings to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32451)

I want to see the used namespaces at a glance and don't want to look up the documentation which namespaces are used globally.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32451#issuecomment-870812382

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>` has to be added to the PropertyGroup in the csproj-file.

For example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If you are using a beta version of .NET 6, you will have to use `<DisableImplicitNamespaceImports>true</DisableImplicitNamespaceImports>`.

Comment: This applies only for .NET 6 beta-versions. For .NET 6 release candidate 1 or newer, set ImplicitUsings to disable.

Comment: Thanks you, it also applies for the released .NET 6.0 LTS version.

Comment: Removing `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` from the project file did not fix the issue but setting it to `disabled` did. My project is multi-targeted: `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>`

Answer (score 14):

In my case I had to remove

```xml
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

from csproj

Answer (score 10):

You cannot.

The question asks how to disable [C# 10's `global using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives) feature, whereby prefixing a `using` directive with `global` applies the directive to the entire compilation unit (usually the project).

The presently accepted answer of disabling [the `ImplicitUsings` MSBuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings) does not affect the `global using` feature. Instead, "implicit `using`s" is a separate feature that builds upon the `global using` feature by automatically, transparently injecting a set of `global using` directives into the compilation unit, the specific assemblies referenced depending on the project type. Disabling the `ImplicitUsings` property prevents this injection but leaves the `global using` directive fully functional.

Comment: the question does mention "_default_ global usings", i.e. implicit usings, not global usings in general. maybe the title should be edited to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

If you moved the script to the global namespace via the rider, then to cancel this you need to go to the file
Assembly-CSharp.csproj.DotSettings, and there find the required line and delete it.