# Create project in Rider for Net5.0 create environment for Net6.0

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, rider

I am trying to create environment for C# in Net5.0 with this settings:

[image]

But after click create it create environment for Net6.0 and I can't build my project.

[image]

Why it happen? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to disable implicit usings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782558/c-sharp-10-disable-global-using

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the csproj and add LangVersion element.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: In csproj I see net5.0 but have implementation for net6.0

Comment: please post (in your original question)...your complete csproj file. (you can leave out packagereferences or project-references)