# Is there a way to disable gutter icons in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 displays symbolic colored icons in the gutter next to line numbers, e.g.

[image: Gutter icons (circled)]

I find the icons distracting and not particularly useful. They seem to be related to code structure — e.g. object inheritance and method overrides — which I can already understand from looking at the code.

Is there a way to "declutter my gutter" by hiding these particular icons?

*I'm not talking about the code folding icons, or breakpoint icons*. These are more or less useful, and less visually distracting.

Visual Studio version used: Preview Version 17.3.0 Preview 2.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These icons are the "Inheritance Margin" icons.  You can disable them by going to Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced and uncheck the "Show inheritance margin" option:

[image]

Comment: As for that top icon that looks like two curly braces `{}`, those are Global Usings (see release notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview)) - I am updating my Visual Studio now and will report back if there is an option to turn those off or not.

Comment: Looks like the same control will also remove those icons (or rather, the entire margin, a.k.a., what you call the gutter).  See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68782817/6530134) if you want to disable Global `using` directives.