# Disable (C# 10) Implicit usings on a specific class

Tags: c#, using, c#-10.0

C# 10 brought implicit usings.

I globaly like them, but they're causing me a conflict on a particular class called Region as there's a conflict with the Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region class.

There's a nice thread here explaining how to disable implicit usings everywhere: [C# 10: Disable Global Using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782558/c-sharp-10-disable-global-using)

I don't want to do it globally, I want to do it just on specific classes. Alternatively, a solution that would allow me to disable a particular implicit using (Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region) would also serve my needs.

Comment: This sounds more like a feature request that should be addressed to Microsoft rather than a question.

Comment: You can still use your own region class by specifying an alias for it without disabling global namespaces: `using MyRegion = YourProject.YourNamespaces.YourRegion;`. That way, you can avoid conflicts and access your own `Region` class via the alias `MyRegion` (just an example name).

Answer (score 4):

To remove implicit namespace for project completely you can use [`Using` xml element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#using) (see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739444/2501279)) with `Remove` attribute:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Remove="Microsoft.Identity.Client" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It also provides option to specify `Condition` attribute but I have not found docs on it for this specific use case.

Comment: There don't need to be specific docs because this works the same as `Condition` does in any other element; general docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions). This is probably not relevant or the OP.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, unfortunately it didn't work: "Error CA1724: The type name Region conflicts in whole or in part with the namespace name 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region'. Change either name to eliminate the conflict."

Comment: @LuisGouveia try removing the namespace - `Remove="Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region"`

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron, but still no luck. I've tried both with Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region and Microsoft.Identity.Client. The output is the same.

Comment: Have you opened `[ProjectName].GlobalUsings.g.cs` to verify what assembly is actually included? And also verified that this assembly is not imported somewhere else? Where did you add the `<ItemGropup>`? You should have a number of `CS0246` in all files that use this assembly, since it can no longer be found, when you have actually removed it from the global include

Comment: @LuisGouveia by the way, this namespace does not look like standard import. What is adding it to global imports (if it is "customly" globally addedd, just remove corresponding `global using`)? What project sdk are you using?

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron, but there aren't any global usings in my project

Comment: @LuisGouveia can you post a [mre] somewhere?