# How to show all using directives - visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net

Thanks you for reading this!
Is there an option in VS 2022 to show all the using directives at the top of the program?
Because I have 2 libraries working with same names, I'm forced to type this long prefix (for the program to distinguish between the 2 libraries). Otherwise I get a CS0104 error
.
[image]

I figure that the recent version of VS 2022 doesn't simply show all using directives at the beginning of the program, so I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 10: Disable Global Using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782558/c-sharp-10-disable-global-using)

Comment: @TimothyG. Well I guess I'm biased having provided an answer,  but the OP asked about "showing" not "disabling".

Comment: Please don't post images. No one can read the tiny exception text.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of [global/implicit using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier). They are automatically generated by the build system.

Example:

```cs
global using global::System;
```

They could really be in an C# file of the project, but the default that the project system generates is in a file called `<projectdir>\obj\<Release|Debug>\<tfm>\<projectname>.GlobalUsings.g.c`. So in a project called `ConsoleApp1.csproj`, targeting .NET 6.0, in Release mode, the file is `obj\Release\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.GlobalUsings.g.cs`.

You can view the file using Windows Explorer, or show all files in Visual Studio.

Example:

[image]

For a standard console project, the content of the file is:

```cs
// <auto-generated/>
global using global::System;
global using global::System.Collections.Generic;
global using global::System.IO;
global using global::System.Linq;
global using global::System.Net.Http;
global using global::System.Threading;
global using global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Those are defined by MSBuild files, by the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#using) item group:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Using Include="System.Collections.Generic"/>
   ...
</ItemGroup>
```

So you could add your own namespaces if you like.

To disable implicit global usings, that is the generation of the `<projectname>.GlobalUsings.g.cs` file, set the `ImplicitUsings` property to `disable` in your csproj file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Make sure to rebuild (or clean) your project after that change, because the originally generated file would otherwise still linger around.